# What is the best practise when we need HTML inside a translation?

Tags: php, internationalization, yii2

I am using Yii2, and I'm facing a situation where I do have some tabs in my page, divided by two HTML tags, like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>
            <div class="text-small">Users</div>
            <span class="text-uppercase">Overview</span>
    </li>
    <li>
            <div class="text-small">Manage</div>
            <span class="text-uppercase">Users</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I could be dividing the string into two variables like "tab_1_line_1", "tab_1_line_2", [...] however I guess it does not really following the i18n standards.

However I guess the following example is not that good aswell:

```
<ul>
    <li>
            <?php \Yii::('app', 'menu_users_overview'); ?>
    </li>
    <li>
            <?php \Yii::('app', 'menu_manage_users'); ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**app.php:**

```
<?php
    return [
        'menu_users_overview' => '<div class="text-small">Users</div><span class="text-uppercase">Overview</span>',
        'menu_manage_users' => '<div class="text-small">Manage</div><span class="text-uppercase">Users</span>',
    ];
?>
```

How should I handle this situation?

Comment: "I guess it does not really following the i18n standards" why do you say that? That is actually the only logical solution because at one point you will want                         <div class="text-small">Product Category</div>
            <span class="text-uppercase">Overview</span>

Answer (score 0):

Your translation shouldn't contain any html, otherwise when you are supporting 20 languages and you decide to change the layout you have to then go and rewrite all the html around the translations.

If you are dead set on the layout you have currently, then another solution would be to have a translation that is an array:

```
<?php
    return [
        'menu_users_overview' =>  ["Users", "Overview"],
        'menu_manage_users' => ["Manage", "Users"],
    ];
?>
```

And then in your HTML use the indexes to get the correct parts, this way your translation is just handling the actual words and not you page structure.

Comment: Do you know if this is a solution currently supported on Yii? Or should I write an wrapper for the function? Would you name your translation strings this way if you do need to translate them?